# Fractions in Latex

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I typed instruction below into a TeX document and the fraction came out smaller than the rest of the equation.
Is there any way of making the *b*, *c* and *d* the same size as the *a*?

```
$a = \frac{b}{c+d}$
```

Comment: inline math is designed to fit into a paragraph without changing the baseline spacing, you could use `\dfrac` from amsmath but if using large expressions it is better to make the whole expression a display and change `$ ... $` to `\[ ..\]`

Comment: If you want an inline fraction bigger than the default \textstyle fraction, you can use the `nccmath ` package: it defines an `\mfrac` command (‘medium-sized fraction’) – about 80 % of `\display style`.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the equation as

```
$a = {\displaystyle\frac{b}{c+d}}$
```

or, after loading `amsmath`,

```
$a = \dfrac{b}{c+d}$
```